# Expecting SELECT or '( ' in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Basically when I register (Registration details goes to Login table), then this data goes to 2 tables:

1. Login table
2. Registration table(Specific)

Using `@Attrib` I check which data needs to go to which table.  But here I am getting an error near the first `else` part.

The error is:

> Incorrect syntax near '@Attrib' expecting SELECT or ,'('

Here is the code:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Registration_SP]
(
    @Email varchar(50),
    @Password varchar(50),
    @Repassword varchar(50),
    @Attrib varchar(50) 
)
AS

BEGIN

    Insert into Login (Email,Password,Repassword,Attrib)
    values(@Email,@Password,@Repassword,@Attrib)

    IF (@Attrib = 'Student')
    BEGIN
        Insert into StudentReg
            (StudentId,FirstName,LastName,Gender,Address1,Address2,Address3,
             LandPhone,MobilePhone,Budget,IsFinancialSupport,CourseName,
             IsJobSeeker,Country,Region,IsSupportActive,RegDate,ImagePath,
             ShortCode)
        Values(@Email,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','')
    END
    ELSE (@Attrib = 'Financial Supporter')
    BEGIN
        Insert into SupporterReg   
        (SupporterId,SupporterName,University,ContactNo,StudentLocation,RegDate,
         ImagePath,ShortCode)
        Values(@Email,'','','','','','','')
    END
```

Further clarification, I have atttached the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `ELSE` is missing `IF` afterwards:

i.e.

```
ELSE (@Attrib = 'Financial Supporter')
```

should be

```
ELSE IF (@Attrib = 'Financial Supporter')
```

Comment: It looks like you also might be missing a final `END` at the end of your `ALTER` statement after I cleaned your code up.  Don't know if this was an accidental ommission or not, thought I would point it out.

Answer (score 6):

An `ELSE` case has no condition, so a syntax error is reported.

```
-- Should be no condition here, syntax error.
ELSE (@Attrib = 'Financial Supporter')
```

I assume you intended it to be `ELSE IF`

```
ELSE
 IF (@Attrib = 'Financial Supporter')
```